# openpyxl corrupts spreadsheet if it contains a data source

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I use openpyxl to interact with Excel files using Python 3.7. I open and save my .xlsx spreadsheets as follows:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb.load_workbook('file.xlsx', read_only=False)
wb.save('file.xlsx')
```

If file.xlsx contains no links to external data sources (such as SQL Server or Postgre-SQL), then there is no problem with the saved file and it opens okay in Excel after being processed by my Python script.

However, if file.xlsx does contain a link to external data, then upon executing the above script, the output file is now corrupted. When opening the file in Excel, the following error is reported and I have the option of attempting to recover it. When recovering, the data remains but all links to the data source are gone.

*> We found a problem with some content in file.xlsx. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.*

It is easy to reproduce this error as follows:

1. Create a blank spreadsheet and save it as file.xlsx.
2. Run the above three lines of Python code to open and save the file. You will see this works fine and has no impact on the spreadsheet.
3. Now open file.xlsx in Excel and, from the Data tab, choose a data source. You can choose any data source (link to a csv file, a table within Excel, or an external data source - it doesn't matter).
4. Save the spreadsheet, then run the above Python script (which again, simply opens and saves it).
5. Open file.xlsx in Excel. You will see that it is now corrupted.

My conclusion is that, at the moment, openpyxl doesn't support spreadsheets that contain links to external data. It would be useful to have this confirmed, or for a workaround to the above issue to be proposed.

Thanks!!

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't suitable for such general questions. You need to be more specific.

Comment: I agree: you couldn't be less specific. Good luck!

Comment: OK, you got me. I will reword the question and try again.

Comment: @shentz if you ever get a solution for this let me know :)